# Input pattern specific format HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a specific format I need in a text box where the user enters a house address for example"45 Ezra ave" The first 3 characters must be numbers followed by a space. The the rest of the string/input can be as many letters as the user needs.

```
<input id="street address" type="text placeholder="address" name="address">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: 2 numbers, followed by a space, followed by one or more of any character:

```
<input pattern="[0-9]{2} .+">
```